# Python inner function can not resolve the local variable of the outer function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined `df` locally in a python function `func1`.
I want subfunction `accumulate_df` to see `df`.
But it gives `Unresolved reference 'df'` error.

I don't want global variable. Results coming from multiple processors will be accumulated in these variables.

I have similar code giving no error. But I couldn't understand what is happening here.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def func1():
    
    # Initialization for accumulated df
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1',
                               'col2',
                               'col3',
                               'col4'])

    df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('string')
    df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(np.float32)
    df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype(np.int32)
    df['col4'] = df['col4'].astype(np.float64)

    def accumulate_df(result_tuple):
        col1_value = result_tuple[0]
        col2_value = result_tuple[1]
        col3_value = result_tuple[2]
        col4_value = result_tuple[3]
        
        if df[(df['col1'] == col1_value) & (df['col2'] == col2_value)].values.any():
            # Update Accumulate
            df.loc[(df['col1'] == col1_value) & (df['col2'] == col2_value), 'col3'] += col3_value
            df.loc[(df['col1'] == col1_value) & (df['col2'] == col2_value), 'col4'] += col4_value

        else:
            df = df.append({'col1': col1_value,
                            'col2': col2_value,
                            'col3': col3_value,
                            'col4': col4_value}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: “Unresolved reference” does not sound like a Python error. Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: @deceze Pycharm shows Unresolved reference 'df' in the IDE.

Comment: so, the linked duplicate explains the fundamental problem, the solution you want here though is to use `nonlocal df`, although, a better solution would be to *return som value from `accumulate_df`, although, you are already mutating  `df` in one of the branches

Comment: But I was resolving a df in a local function (accumulate_df) without explicit nonlocal df. I have such a code for which Pycharm IDE doesn't give the error. But why now?

Comment: Probably because you're not *assigning to `df`* in that other code…? [*"Python treats variables in functions differently depending on whether you assign values to them…"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370363/476)

Comment: No, the inner accumulate function always updates the local variables of the outer function. That is the aim of the inner accumulate function which will be called multiple times from multiple processors. And returning df in the outer function doesn't help. Is there a solution wo nonlocal df?

Comment: If you write `df =` inside a function, that scopes the name `df` as a local variable inside that function. If you want to tell Python that you mean to assign to the already existing `df` one scope higher, you need to do so by declaring `nonlocal df` in the function. Do you understand this? Why don't you want to do this when this is quite apparently what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks @deceze. I think I'm stuck with the idea of how a former similar code was working without error and without nonlocal df.

Comment: Again, probably because you only had `df[..] += ...` statements in there, not `df = ...`?!

Comment: Exactly! if I just write df[...] += .... Error is gone. Why?

Comment: Because that’s manipulating an object, not assigning a variable.